# Java Pattern.matcher(StringBuffer), why it does not behave the same way as Pattern.matcher(String)?

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I need to "shorten" a string in a loop before passing it again and again to be matched by a `java.regex.Pattern`. Probably a trivial situation for some deeply involved in parsing and text processing.

I am faced with the situation that I have to use:

```
string=string.substring(shortenHowMuch); //Need to shorten it from the beginning
```

...which low level developers very well know, that is copying the entire string into another address of the memory.  Even with HotSpot's optimisations in place (which I am aware of), I still need to make sure the code runs in maximum possible performance variant on all possible Java VMs.

**Edit:**
Later I found out, that my statement above, that it is copying the string, is wrong. So my very question should go "to hell" :) Anyway, read if you like :) `.substring` does not copy, but instead  it does share a reference to a `char[]`, very interesting :)

Comment: It would be more helpful for you to post real code that you are trying if possible, than to demonstrate the problem with a theoretical explanation.

Comment: Well, one obvious answer to the question posed in the title is that a `StringBuffer` is not the same thing as a `String`.

Comment: @JackManey: but `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` both implement `CharSequence`, which is the argument to `Pattern`'s static `.matcher()` method

Comment: `"that is copying the entire string into another address of the memory"` actually substring copies only reference to `char[]` table that stores content of original String. This way new String only needs information about `start` and `end` indexes that should it use.

Comment: More generally, why this concern over the performance? Don't forget that JVMs have JIT, and the JIT is smarter than you in any case, so...

Comment: @Pshemo: I didn't know that, thank you. this solves every performance concern referenced in my question.

Comment: @fge: Allow me to disagree. It does depend on the particular JVM whether it's JIT is smart enough or not. Do not over-estimate them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not explain what exactly happened when you used StringBuilder so I cannot answer why. But actually you don't need StringBuilder because String.substring is optimized and it does not copy the internal char array. This is what happens internally

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
        ..... 
        return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == count)) ? this :
            new String(offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
 }

// Package private constructor which shares value array for speed.
String(int offset, int count, char value[]) {
    this.value = value;
    this.offset = offset;
    this.count = count;
}
```

Comment: Yeaaaah! :) Indeed. I can see now in jdk code. It does share a reference to a char[] :) I didn't know this, rly :) So obvious to do, but did not guess, and didn't bother to check :) Thank you, this was my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing the code but can you instead make your pattern more general? Something like ".*original-pattern"?

Comment: A bad regex seems to be the most likely cause of the asker wanting to shorten the string repeatedly.

Comment: This is even worse performance-wise, since `.*` will swallow the whole string before reverting to match the rest of the regex. But then we have no idea what the input looks like etc, so...